# Closed form exists in term of $\gamma$

Tags: integration

An interesting integral resulting in an approximate in term of Euler-Mascheroni constant

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left({e^{-x}\arctan{x}\over x}\right)^2\mathrm dx\approx1-\gamma\tag1$$

> Does this integral $(1)$ has a closed form in term of Euler-Mascheroni constant?

Comment: Mascheroni, please (this makes a different pronunciation).

Comment: The Inverse Symbolic Calculator found nothing (using $0.4227676505078677029$).

Comment: ...........nope..........